# How to import recursively all classes in a module?

Tags: python-3.x, module

Is it possible to use `__all__` recursively?
This imports modules in `__all__` ...

```
from mypkg import *
```

but not recursively.

Trying to put everything into `__all__` (inside `__init__.py`) doesn't seem to be useful either:

```
from pathlib import Path

# List all python (.py) files in the current folder and put them as __all__
fs = [f for f in Path('mypkg/').rglob('*.py') if not f.name.endswith('__init__.py')]
__all__ = [str(f).replace('/','.')[:-3][5:] for f in fs]
```

Since...

```
from mypkg import *
```

Results in `AttributeError: module 'mypkg' has no attribute 'module1.file1'` for the first folder in the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this to `__init__.py`. May not be the best approach for most situations, but it is good enough for my use case.

```
from pathlib import Path

# Include all classes when 'from mypkg import *' is called. 
fs = [f for f in Path('mypkg').rglob('*.py') if not f.name.startswith('_')]

for f in [str(f).replace('/', '.')[:-3] for f in fs]:
    statement = f'from {f} import *'
    exec(statement)
```